# Scala return value calculated in foreach

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am new new to **scala and spark** and trying to understand few basic stuff out here.

Spark version used 1.5.

why does value of sum does not get updated in below foreach loop.

```
var sum=1;
df.select("column1").distinct().foreach(row=>{ 
sum = sum +1
})
println("SUM = "sum)
```

--> **SUM = 1**

I am trying to understand whats **scope of variable** referred in for-each. What if i need to do some math inside and get the result of it outside the for loop.

My use case to understand above is to get  unique values in loop and append it to list of String.

Comment: You should mention you use Spark not just in tags, because it matters. This would work perfectly well with Scala collections.

Answer (score 7):

The way you reason about the program is wrong. `foreach` is executed independently on each executor and modifies its own copy of `sum`. There is no global shared state here. Just count values directly:

```
df.select("column1").distinct.count
```

If you really want to handle this manually you'll need some type of `reduce`:

```
df.select("column1").distinct.rdd.map(_ => 1L).reduce(_ + _)
```

Comment: thaks @zero323 how do i store value across iteration in this case. i want to get distinct values in column as list of string

Comment: `distinct.collect.toList`

Answer (score 2):

Read the Programming Guide, it has a section devoted to this: [Understanding Closures](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#understanding-closures-a-nameclosureslinka). If you actually need to collect some state, you can use Accumulators (but note that you can't access the value from the executor nodes, only amend it). But try doing without them first: think in terms of available transformations instead of mutating state.